# logrotation size limit is not effecting

Tags: linux, logrotate

I have fixed size limit in logrotation 1M. The script run on every hours even though its rotating less than 1Mb files. I dont know what i have done wrong. Below is my configuration parameters.

```
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.4/data/pg_log/postgresql-* 
{
              rotate 25
              size=1M
              notifempty
              missingok
              olddir /opt/PostgreSQL/8.4/data/pg_log/test
              copytruncate
}
```

Please can anyone  help me out in this problem?

Lot of Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `size 1M` without equal sign.

Comment: Even I tried that then also its rotating the less than 1mb files..!!!

Comment: This is wrong. With and without the equals sign are both valid and equivalent syntax. See, for example, [this man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) which includes both syntaxes. I am using the equals sign in a logrotate file for Apache in production and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You may check the logging parameters in your PostgreSQL config, see: [PostgreSQL Error Reporting and Logging](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-logging.html) (e.g. log_rotation_size).